# Schedule times overwritten with Schedule module when called via array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, schedule

I'm attempting to build an alarm application but I'm struggling to get the 'schedule' module to function how I'd like it to. The problem is that I can't seem to schedule *multiple alarms for one day* while calling the day attribute via an array.

Example of how you'd normally schedule multiple times for one day:

```
schedule.every().sunday.at('17:25').do(job)
schedule.every().sunday.at('17:30').do(job)
schedule.every().sunday.at('17:35').do(job)
```

This works fine, but I really want to load times with a for loop so I don't have a giant if statement, and so that I can load times dynamically:

```
dayArray = [
schedule.every().sunday,
schedule.every().monday,
schedule.every().tuesday,
schedule.every().wednesday,
schedule.every().thursday,
schedule.every().friday,
schedule.every().saturday
]

for i in range(1, xlsxAlarmSheet.ncols):
                for j in range(1, 8):
                    if(str(xlsxAlarmSheet.cell_value(j, i)) != '0'):
                        dayArray[j - 1].at(str(xlsxAlarmSheet.cell_value(j, i))[:2] + ':' + str(xlsxAlarmSheet.cell_value(j, i))[2:]).do(job)
```

The  days are being loaded from an array and the times from an xlsx file via the XLRD module. The only problem is the alarms are overwriting each other somehow when I schedule multiple times for one day. If I schedule 3 times for Sunday with this method for example, only the third scheduled time fires off. I thought it must be because when I load the days into an array they are no longer unique somehow, so I tried doing a 2-dimensional array:

```
dayArray = [[
schedule.every().sunday,
schedule.every().monday,
schedule.every().tuesday,
schedule.every().wednesday,
schedule.every().thursday,
schedule.every().friday,
schedule.every().saturday
]] * (xlsxAlarmSheet.ncols - 1)

for i in range(1, xlsxAlarmSheet.ncols):
                for j in range(1, 8):
                    if(str(xlsxAlarmSheet.cell_value(j, i)) != '0'):
                        dayArray[i - 1][j - 1].at(str(xlsxAlarmSheet.cell_value(j, i))[:2] + ':' + str(xlsxAlarmSheet.cell_value(j, i))[2:]).do(job)
```

With no luck... the times are still overwriting each other, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[In another question I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58458664/increment-schedule-modules-day-attribute-with-variable-in-python/58458718#58458718), I was originally trying to substitute the day attribute with a string, like Vig is suggesting with his answer to this post. This wasn't working for me, so I ended up storing objects in an array, as Prune suggested on my original question.

However, Prune also posted [a link](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/82317/schedule.every) to an example (example 7) in which the entire call to schedule a time was stored in a string and then called via `eval()`, which seems to work.

So this is what I ended up doing:

```
dayArray = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday']
dayTimeArray = []

for i in range(1, xlsxAlarmSheet.ncols):
    for j in range(1, 8):
        if(str(xlsxAlarmSheet.cell_value(j, i)) != '0'):
            dayTimeArray.append(
                "schedule.every().{}.at('{}').do(StartSubProcess)".format(
                    dayArray[j - 1], 
                    str(xlsxAlarmSheet.cell_value(j, i))[:2] + ':' + str(xlsxAlarmSheet.cell_value(j ,i))[2:]
                )
            )

for i in range(0, len(dayTimeArray)):
    eval(dayTimeArray[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: 0 Python experience, only JavaScript.... But...

Try to not call the function within the array of objects like that:

```
dayArray = [[
schedule.every().sunday,
...
```

Instead just have the name of the day (the only part which is varying)

```
dayArray = [[
'sunday', 'monday', ...
```

Then in the for each use that string name when you build the function

```
for each .... { schedule.every()[dayArray[i]].at(...).do(...) }
```

My random guess is that it's somehow getting called incorrectly when stored that way, just store the part that is different (the day name), since you can just call the rest of that function in the loop (since it's the same for all).

Hopefully that makes sense.  No idea if it will work, just something to try.  Good luck.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work, this is actually originally how I tried doing this. Not being able to get that to work was actually one of my other questions from a few days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58458664/increment-schedule-modules-day-attribute-with-variable-in-python/58458718#58458718

Comment: You put me back on the right track, see my answer for more details, thanks!

Comment: Awesome!  Happy to be of some help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need to use an index to store your values. This link might help. 
https://treyhunner.com/2016/04/how-to-loop-with-indexes-in-python/#What_if_we_need_indexes?

Comment: Please add more details into your post.